# Ruby/Jekyll unknown error when running -watch

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've just started playing around with Ruby and Jekyll and I've been using the `-watch` command from CLI to automatically update the Jekyll site. However after a brief computer restart I'm seeing the following error when running `jekyll -watch`

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/program.rb:30:in `go': invalid option: -watch (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary.rb:22:in `program'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/bin/jekyll:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Since I'm new to Ruby, I have no idea why the above error is occurring. Can someone please help me explain why I'm getting the above error and sort it out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems here.  First, since you're using the long form of the watch option, you'll need to use two hyphens: `--watch` (or you could use the short form `-w`).  Second, jekyll is looking for a subcommand such as `build` or `serve`, which you haven't provided.

I'm not sure exactly what command you are trying to issue, but it should look something like this:

```
jekyll build --watch
```

or

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

For more information check out [jekyll basic usage](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/).