# Ruby/Jekyll requirement errors when serving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jekyll-theme

I recently installed Windows Subsystem for Linux and I'm running the Ubuntu distro on my Windows 10 computer. I installed Python, pip, Ruby, and Jekyll and they are all confirmed to be installed properly when I run the --version flags.

I am trying to run and modify a Jekyll theme called [Mediumish](https://bootstrapstarter.com/bootstrap-templates/template-mediumish-bootstrap-jekyll/) locally on my computer. When following the author's instructions (i.e. run `bundle` and run `jekyll serve --watch`), I encounter the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.6/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:48:in `require_from_bundler'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

I have tried submitting issues to the author's Github account, but it appears he has stopped replying (and maintaining) this theme for a few months.

I found another Stackoverflow post titled [Ruby/Jekyll unknown error when running -watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830263/ruby-jekyll-unknown-error-when-running-watch) — which is very similar to what I'm experiencing. I have tried the recommended solutions from this post which are to run the `jekyll build --watch` and `jekyll serve --watch` commands, but the same errors occur.

I was able to successfully run this theme a few months ago, but after reformatting my computer, reinstalling all my applications from scratch, and cloning a new copy of the theme from the author's website, I am unable to serve the website locally thus impeding me from viewing any modifications I make to the blog theme.

Comment: Maybe you need to install `bundler`?  One way to install is by running command `gem install bundler`

Comment: Can you try running `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` instead?

Comment: @Kin I ran `gem install bundler` as you suggested and received the following message: ```Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed```, but I am still receiving the same errors.

Comment: @JayDorsey Running the `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` command returns the following error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)```

Comment: I want to say this was a known issue. There's 2 things I can think of: 1) run `gem update --system` 2) double check your bundler version with `bundle --version` and make sure it's 2.0.2; it might be defaulting to an older version. I think the system update would fix it though, if it's what I think it is

Comment: @JayDorsey I was able to confirm I am running bundler version 2.0.2. Running `gem update --system` almost fixed the issue, but I'm encountering a new error. (I may have to split the error in several comments:) ```Error: could not read file /mnt/c/Users/muyga/Desktop/mediumish-theme-jekyll/vendor/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb: Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in ```

Comment: @JayDorsey Error cont'd: ```the YAML front matter.
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.```

Answer (score 1):

I ran the `gem update --system` command and my Jekyll theme *almost* served locally.

I received the following error:

```
Error: could not read file /mnt/c/Users/muyga/Desktop/mediumish-theme-jekyll/vendor/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb: Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter. ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT: ------------------------------------ Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
```

In order to fix that error, I modified my `config.yml` file and added `vendor` to the `exclude:` category to exclude that folder within my theme folder.

Now when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` the theme serves properly.

Thanks to @JayDorsey and [Jekyll: Error: Site could not be built, wrong date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915298/jekyll-error-site-could-not-be-built-wrong-date-format)
 for the solutions!